# Controlling the "IdleCallback" in Haskell OpenGL (or triggering the "DisplayCallback")

Tags: haskell, opengl

I have done a package to draw implicit surfaces with OpenGL in Haskell. It is available in [my github repo](https://github.com/stla/opengl-implicit). But it is extremely slow and that's why I have a dozen of questions about my practice of Haskell OpenGL. Here is a first one.

I always define this `idleCallback`:

```
idle :: IdleCallback
idle = postRedisplay Nothing
```

and in the `main` file I include it with:

```
  idleCallback $= Just idle
```

Then, when I do that, I have noticed the following thing. If I include for example

```
putStrLn "hello"
```

in the `DisplayCallback`, then, when I run the program, `hello` is repeatedly printed in the terminal window at a phenomenal speed. This means the `DisplayCallback` is "scanned" each time `hello` is printed. So if my `DisplayCallBack` generates e.g. a myriad of triangles to be displayed, I'm afraid this repeated "scanning" should cause an issue. No ?

And this is due to the `IdleCallback`. Indeed, I have tried

```
  idleCallback $= Nothing
```

Then the graphics is displayed as expected and:

1. `hello` does not repeatedly appear anymore on the terminal window
2. the "actions" I defined in `KeyboardCallback` (such as rotation of the graphic) do not work anymore except if - see 3
3. but, if I press a key generating such an action, while it has no direct effect, its effect correctly occurs *after I press the left mouse button*, and `hello` appears on the screen; thus it seems that the left mouse button triggers the "redisplay" of the graphic (the `DisplayCallback`).

Therefore I'm wondering: isn't it preferable to always do `idleCallback $= Nothing` and then to do something (but **what/how**, that's my question) that triggers the "redisplay" when one presses a key introduced in the `KeyboardCallback` ?

I don't think that would overcome my slowness problem but anyway this is one of the questions I'm wondering about. Hope the question is clear...

To sum up, the `DisplayCallback` is always updated even if it doesn't need to be updated, when one does `idleCallback $= Just idle`. I'm looking for something which updates the `DisplayCallback` only when needed, i.e. when and only when we press a key introduced in the `KeyboardCallback` or another such callback (`MouseCallback`, etc).

Comment: I don't know haskell, but [postRedisplay](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.13/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Window.html#v:postRedisplay) seems to me what you need for "forcing" a redrawn.

Comment: So I should include it in the `KeyboardCallback` ? I'll try later. I'm currently installing my package on a better computer to check whether the performance is better.

Comment: Yes, in all callbacks (keyboard, mouse, window resize, etc) that imply a window redraw. Don't do it in `idleCallback`, you may get an endless loop.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes you're right, this works in the `KeyBoardCallBack`. Thanks.

Comment: @Ripi2 And that strongly improves the slowness problem (but this is still slow nevertheless). Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: As I said, I don't know Haskell. But you can write the answer, showing some useful code, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ripi2, I've found the solution. It's indeed better to do

```
idleCallback $= Nothing
```

in the `main` file, and then to trigger the `DisplayCallback` in the `KeyboardCallback`, with the help of `postRedisplay`. More precisely, I've replaced

```
keyboard :: IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -- rotations
         -> IORef Double -> IORef Double -- parameters a and b
         -> IORef Double -- isolevel
         -> IORef Double -- zoom
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot1 rot2 rot3 a b l zoom c _ = 
  case c of
    'e' -> rot1 $~! subtract 2
    'r' -> rot1 $~! (+ 2)
    .......
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()
```

with

```
keyboard :: IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -- rotations
         -> IORef Double -> IORef Double -- parameters a and b
         -> IORef Double -- isolevel
         -> IORef Double -- zoom
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot1 rot2 rot3 a b l zoom c _ = do
  case c of
    'e' -> rot1 $~! subtract 2
    'r' -> rot1 $~! (+ 2)
    .......
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()
  postRedisplay Nothing
```

This improves the slowness problem as expected (but it's still slow however).